# Product with 0 Price not appearing

Tags: magento-2.1.7, product-page

Magento Version: 2.1.7 EE Theme: Ultimo Theme - Infortis.

My product page seems to be blank when i have a price of 0.00, but if i make it 0.01+ the product page works fine.

As i need all my products to not have a price, any ideas how i can fix this?

Seems to be put on hold requiring more information but i have no idea what information you would like me to supply?

Comment: Looks like its your theme or some custom module issue ,i have checked on default 2.1.7 EE and its working fine